# How to compare Row by Row using Pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to coding and I really need help in finding out how I can come up with a code to compare my data. Due to privacy reasons, I am unable to show you my real data but here is an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98MGr.png)

I would like to compare all electric Type 1 pokemons & their HP, row by row. An example would be:

row1 compared with row2 (Pikachu vs. Raichu)
row1 compared with row3 (Pikachu vs. Magnemite)

And also:

row2 compared with row3 (Raichu vs. Magnemite)
row2 compared with row4 (Raichu vs. Magneton)

and the list goes on... basically the first row I'm comparing should always loop to +1.

I'm currently using **pandas** to solve my code and this is what i came with so far:

```
for i in range(1,15):
    a = df["(x)"].iloc[0]
    b = df["(y)"].iloc[0]
    c = df["(x)"].iloc[i]
    d =  df["(y)"].iloc[i]
```

where x = Type 1 and y = HP.

Would really appreciate if anyone is able to give some suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output? Going row-by-row like this can get really, really slow and there might be a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: Hi richard! for my actual data, i would require to do pairwise comparison. In this case, I would need to compare the HP for each Electric pokemon to see if it is similar or not.

So i would need to compare every pokemon with each other in order to find differences/similarities between them.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want a list like this: ['Pikachu vs. Raichu', 'Raichu vs. Magnemite', ...]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self join could be a solution for this. Here is a demonstration on mock data.

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id  last_name   gender  age
0   1   Vyel    Male    66
1   2   Allsebrook  Male    50
2   3   Prinett Male    30
3   4   Jinda   Male    31
4   5   Coram   Female  21
```

I want to compare each men's (Male, or Electric type in your case) age (or HP). Merging the dataframe with itself will result in a dataframe with any combination of two men:

```
df_merged = df.merge(df[df['gender']=='Male'], on = 'gender')
df_merged.head()
```

Output:

```
    id_x    last_name_x gender  age_x   id_y    last_name_y age_y
0   1   Vyel    Male    66  1   Vyel    66
1   1   Vyel    Male    66  2   Allsebrook  50
2   1   Vyel    Male    66  3   Prinett 30
3   1   Vyel    Male    66  4   Jinda   31
4   2   Allsebrook  Male    50  1   Vyel    66
```

The filtering `df[df['gender']=='Male']` makes sure it only contains Men.

You can ofcourse drop rows containing the same person twice:

```
df_merged.loc[df_merged['last_name_x'] != df_merged['last_name_y']]
```

From here you can compare them with standard dataframe operations, e.g. making an `older` column containing the person with higher age:

```
df_merged['older'] = df_merged.apply(lambda row: row['last_name_x'] if row['age_x'] > row['age_y'] else row['last_name_y'], 
                                    axis = 1)
```

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your response :) This gave me what I wanted. You are awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: Using your output, how can i prevent repeated combinations? Let's say from your output above, in index 1, there is a combination of Vyel & Allsebrook and in index 4 it has the same combination 

Is there any way I can remove at least one of them to prevent overlapping data?

Comment: Suppose you have the output in `df_out` you can keep the rows where the older person is in the `last_name_x` column: `df_out[df_out['last_name_x']==df_out['older']]`